# Getting Error ` Incorrect syntax near '`'. ` When Creating a MSSQL Table Using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a PHP page to create a MSSQL Table for my website's shopping cart. When I run the PHP page on my website, it says I have incorrect syntax near '`'. I don't understand why I am getting this error as I don't even have that character in my PHP code.

Here is my full PHP page code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'a6';
$dbuser = 'roaot';
$dbpass = 'rootpaaassword';
 $conn=mssql_connect('gacom','Gar','Ra1!');
mssql_select_db('Gaer',$conn);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

$CREATE = 'CREATE TABLE products (
  id int(11) IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  product_code varchar(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  product_name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  product_desc tinytext NOT NULL,
  product_img_name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL)';

mssql_select_db('GBMTrailer');
$retval = mssql_query( $CREATE, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create table:');
}
echo "Table created!!\n";
mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Comment: You've verified that the SQL in the code works with MS SQL Server?

Comment: No, the SQL code has not been verified that it works with my MS SQL server. Previously the code did have ` around the table name and column names in the SQL code. I got the same error before I took the ` character out, and I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try **int** instead **int(11)**

and **varchar(255)** instead **tinytext**

```
  CREATE TABLE products (
  id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  product_code varchar(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  product_name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  product_desc varchar(255)NOT NULL,
  product_img_name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Yeah OP should use MSSQL DDL rather than MySQL DDL since ... it's MSSQL.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I am new to MSSQL, and I am not quite familiar with the coding, yet.